# Ternary operator on Radio Button

Tags: php, html, if-statement, ternary-operator

I am new to PHP/Programming. I am unable to understand this ternary operator condition used for radio buttons. Can anyone tell me how do I convert this to simple `if else` type condition.?

```
<?php if($_POST['midnightdelivery'])
    {
        echo ($_POST['midnightdelivery'] == 0)?'checked="checked"':'';
    }
else
    { 
        echo 'checked="checked"'; 
    }
?>
```

I checked this [This](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/4) for understanding ternary Operator. But I couldn't understand same operator in mine case.

Update:Also can someone give me an example of `if-elseif -else` to ternary opertaor?

Comment: What you are doing is using both `if else` and `ternary` within your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below code will help you to understand ternary operator......

below code is for current_file.php using if elseif else.....

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        if($gender == male)
        {
            $selected_radio_button = "checked='checked'";
        }
        elseif($gender == female)
        {
            $selected_radio_button = "checked='checked'";
        }
        else
        {
            $selected_radio_button = "";
        }
        ?>
        <form action="#">
            <input type='radio' name='gender' value='male' <?php echo $selected_radio_button; ?>> Male
            <input type='radio' name='gender' value='female' <?php echo $selected_radio_button; ?>> Female
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <form name='rform' method='post' action='current_file.php'>
         <input type='radio' name='gender' value='male'> Male
         <input type='radio' name='gender' value='female'> Female
         <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
    </form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Now, below code is for current_file.php using ternary operator......

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        ($gender == "male" || $gender == "female") ? $selected_radio_button = "checked='checked'" : $selected_radio_button = "";
        ?>
        <form action="#">
            <input type='radio' name='gender' value='male' <?php echo $selected_radio_button; ?>> Male
            <input type='radio' name='gender' value='female' <?php echo $selected_radio_button; ?>> Female
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <form name='rform' method='post' action='current_file.php'>
         <input type='radio' name='gender' value='male'> Male
         <input type='radio' name='gender' value='female'> Female
         <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
    </form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Both servers same result but ternary operator use less line of code....
Hope this will help you...

Comment: Thank you.Its as expected explanation (with example).

Answer (score 0):

Radio button `$_POST['midnightdelivery']` will pass its value,  not 1 or 0 for checked or not checked.

you can set radio button as follows, to get 1 or 0 for checked and not checked.

```
<input name="midnightdelivery" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input name="midnightdelivery" type="radio" value="0"  />
```

and you can use

```
echo ($_POST['midnightdelivery'] == '1')?'checked="checked"':'';
```